# Can't attach 2nd interface to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've got 2 instances running nicely

```
web - t2.medium - us-east-1d - Private IP - 10.1.1.6
vpn - t2.micro  - us-east-1d - EIP assigned
```

I'm trying to add a 2nd interface onto the vpn server within the 10.1.1.0/24 network.

After I create an interface I can't attach it to the vpn.  The web instance shows up to attach but that's already on the internal network.

How can I get a 2nd interface within the 10.1.1.0/24 network onto the vpn server?

VPC setup:

```
internal: CIDR - 10.1.1.0/24      - us-east-1d (web server)
vpn:      CIDR - 192.168.247.0/24 - us-east-1d (vpn server)
```

I've also tried to manage the priv IP addresses on the vpn server to see if I could assign an internal to it but it comes up with:

> "IP Address not in Subnet"

I need the vpn server to have 2 network interfaces: 1 public and 1 private/internal.

Comment: Was the ENI created in the same VPC and AZ as the VPN instance? They need to match.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to assign an IP that isn't in that *subnet* range. if your instance is in `subnet-foo` and `subnet-foo` is us-east-1a with `10.1.1.0/24` it should work. It would fail for instance if you tried to attach a nic with IP `10.0.1.6` in my example. Your error message is pretty specific that your IP address is not in that subnet CIDR rang